# Domino AppDev Pack TypeError: database.useAgent is not a function

Tags: node.js, lotus-domino, hcl, domino-appdev-pack

I am using the AppDev Pack to create an API for a domino database. Currently trying only the sample code present in the Domino AppDev Pack. Here is the code:

```
app.get("/lastUpdated", (req, res, next) => {
  //const operationName = req.params.operationName;
  console.log("0");
  const agentRunExample = (async () => {
    console.log("1");
    // Initialize the Server, Database and Agent objects.
    const server = await useServer(serverConfig);
    console.log("2");
    const database = await server.useDatabase({ filePath: 'develop/node-demo.nsf' });
    console.log("3");
    const agent = await database.useAgent({ name: 'AppDevLastModified' });
    console.log("4");
    // Create the context document with data to pass to the agent.
    const contextUnid = await database.createDocument({
      document: {
        param1: 'aa',
        param2: 'bb',
      },
    });
    console.log("5");
    // * a context document that the agent can read/write
    await agent.run({
      //selection: { search: { query: "Form = 'VA'" } },
      context: { unid: contextUnid },
    });
    console.log("6");
    // sample agent updates the 'found_docs' item.
    const result = await database.bulkReadDocumentsByUnid({
      unids: [contextUnid],
      itemNames: ['found_docs'],
    });
    console.log("7");
    // Return the latest copy of the context document.
    const [doc] = result.documents;
    return doc;
  })().catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  console.log("end0");

  res.json(agentRunExample);

  console.log("end1");

});
```

The general APIs are working, but in this case, I am getting the error when setting the agent.

```
TypeError: database.useAgent is not a function
```

Can anybody suggest what I am missing here? Remember this is the sample code given in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you use Domino AppDev Pack version 1.0.4 and later as [useAgent](https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/domino-db-reference.html#useagent) was first introduced in 1.0.4.

Comment: Hi Henrik, Firstly thank you for your correction in question formatting. I am using the domino-appdev-pack-1.0.5. I believe this should work then, but it is giving this error.